# Display no results component when there are no results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show the no results components whenever the api has finished loading and when no results are returned. The issue I'm having, is I am seeing the no results components displayed first for a few seconds and then the results showing whenever the api returns data. I should never want to see the no results component showing if there are results returned from the api.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import NoResults from './NoResults';

const Users = () => {

  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [isResultsLoading, setIsResultsLoading] = useState(true);

  const isLoading = () => {
    if (isResultsLoading) return <ResultsLoader />;
    if (results && results.length > 0)
      return (
        <UserTableWrapper>
          <UserTable
            data={results}
          />
        </UserTableWrapper>
      );
    return <NoResults heading="No users available." />;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    const getData = async () => {
      if (isMounted) {
        const users = await fetchUsers(); // is just an api call
        if (users && users.length > 0) return { users, loading: false };
        return { users: null, loading: true };
      }
      return { users: null, loading: true };
    };
    getData().then(({ users, loading }) => {
      if (isMounted) {
        if (users) setResults(users);
        setIsResultsLoading(loading);
      }
    });
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
        <h1>Users</h1>
        {isLoading()}
    </>
  );
};
};


export default Users;
```

Comment: You can conditionally render in your return method. No need for extraneous functions. Just check your results and set it with a ternary operator - `return { !isResultsLoading && results ? <Finished /> : <Loading />}`

Comment: Can you edit my code please @JoelHager just so i can understand

Comment: It's a little spaghetti right now. Can you walk me through what it is you're trying to accomplish, and what *actual* things are you verifying before running getData()? You just don't need a *lot* of these conditionals. Looks like you're just trying to get a list of users?

Comment: Im trying to get a list of users from an api call called fetchUsers(). I am able to show the users, but am not able to show the no results component when there are no users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check for the length of `results` with `results.length` since `results` already exists as an empty array.
2. When you get your data and parse it simply set both the states for `results` with the data, and `isLoading` to `false`.
3. Perhaps rename the `isLoading` function to something more representative of what the function *does*. I've called mine `getJSX`.

Here's a working example that uses a mock API. (Note I've had to use this without `async` and `await` because snippets haven't caught up with the latest Babel version.) You can change the JSON that's returned by the API by uncommenting/commenting out the JSON statements in the first couple of lines.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const json= '[1, 2, 3, 4]';
// const json = '[]';

function mockApi() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(json), 3000);
  });
}

function Example() {

  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [isResultsLoading, setIsResultsLoading] = useState(true);

  function getJSX() {
    if (isResultsLoading) return <div>Loading</div>;
    if (results.length) {
      return results.map(el => <div>{el}</div>);
    }
    return <div>No users available.</div>;
  };
        
  useEffect(() => {
    mockApi()
      .then(res => JSON.parse(res))
      .then(data => {
        setResults(data);
        setIsResultsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
  
  return <div>{getJSX()}</div>

};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy but i don't think you's understand what Im asking here. If i could show a video or something.

Comment: Like Drew said you shouldn't be seeing the `<NoResults>` component at all if you have users. Running my code proves that.

Comment: When I know there will be results and i refresh the page I get the following behaviour:
I see "No users available" message for like a second and then results show.
Is there any way I can stop this the message from showing?

Comment: Yes, but you also have lots of people telling you that your code is over-complicated, and that you might be able to eliminate the issue if you remove all those unnecessary conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

You should rely on conditional rendering and simplify your logic a little bit.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import NoResults from "./NoResults";

const Users = () => {
  // This holds the results - default to null till we get a successful API response
  const [results, setResults] = useState(null);
  // This should be a boolean stating if the API call is pending
  const [isResultsLoading, setIsResultsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const users = await fetchUsers(); // is just an api call
      if (users && users.length > 0) {
        // if the result is good, store it
        setResults(users);
      }
      // By the way, the api call is finished now
      setIsResultsLoading(false);
    };
    getData();
  }, []); // no deps => this effect will run just once, when the component mounts

  if (isResultsLoading) {
    // Render nothing while API call is pending
    return null;
  } else {
    if (results) {
      // The API has returned a good result, so render it!
      return (
        <UserTableWrapper>
          <UserTable data={results} />
        </UserTableWrapper>
      );
    } else {
      // No good result, render the fallback component
      return <NoResults heading="No users available." />;
    }
  }
};

export default Users;
```

Comment: I like you refactored code but its not what I want to solve. Whenever i refresh the page I still get a glimpse of the <NoResults heading="No users available." />; whenever there are results.

Comment: You can create a global flag called `loading` and set it to true initially, after your successful API call in useEffect, you can set the `loading` flag to false, and then add it to your conditional rendering: `return loading ? <NoResults/> : <Users />`

Comment: When I know there will be results and i refresh the page I get the following behaviour:
I see "No users available" message for like a second and then results show.
Is there any way I can stop this the message from showing?

Answer (score 1):

You've a lot of extraneous conditionals and code duplication (not as DRY as it could be). Try cutting down on the user checks before you've even updated state, and you likely don't need the mounted check. Conditionally render the UI in the return.

```
const Users = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [isResultsLoading, setIsResultsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers() // is just an api call
      .then(users => {
        setResults(users);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle any errors, etc...
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsResultsLoading(false); // <-- clear loading state regardless of success/failure
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
        <h1>Users</h1>
        {isResultsLoading ? (
          <ResultsLoader />
        ) : results.length ? ( // <-- any non-zero length is truthy
          <UserTableWrapper>
            <UserTable data={results} />
          </UserTableWrapper>
        ) : (
          <NoResults heading="No users available." />
        )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I like you refactored code but its not what I want to solve. Whenever i refresh the page I still get a glimpse of the <NoResults heading="No users available." />; whenever there are results. –

Comment: @StevenDornan I don't see how that's possible when initial `isResultsLoading` state is true. Can you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces your issue for us to inspect and live debug?

Comment: have you got any software i can send you a video instead?

Comment: When I know there will be results and i refresh the page I get the following behaviour:
I see "No users available" message for like a second and then results show.
Is there any way I can stop this the message from showing?

Comment: @StevenDornan The UI logic has to get through *two* conditional tests before it can render the "NoResults" component: loading ***has*** to be false and there ***has*** to be an empty `results` array. Videos are nice for seeing the UI, but we would prefer to see what your code is doing with your specific set of reproduction steps.

Comment: No problem i have it sorted.